# Access drop down list from code behind

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I have an .aspx file that has 3 drop down lists:
ddlMake
ddlModel
ddlColour

i have a Page_Load function but i cant acces them in the Page_Load function...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace NorthwindCascading
{
    public partial class _IndexBasic : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                CarService service = new CarService();
                List<string> Makes = service.GetCarMakes();
                ddlMake.DataSource = Makes;
                ddlMake.DataBind();
                ddlMake.Items.Insert(0, " -- Select Make -- ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the code-behind file manually so i guess i am missing something... it just says that the `ddlMake` element is not defined in current context...any suggestions?

Comment: must be some aspx markup validation problem.. check if all tags are correctly closed

Comment: can you check if it is runat server???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than figure out what went wrong. I suggest you just simply delete the file and re-do what you have done again. Will save your time....

Comment: Yeah!! sometime, it's kinda annoyed to debug something like that. Glad to hear your problem's been solved. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CodeFile/CodeBehind attribute in the page directive is pointing to the correct file.  If so, make sure the Inherits attribute in the page directive is naming the correct class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the code behind manually, then the `_IndexBasic.designer.cs` probably doesn't contain the `protected` members, which would be why you cannot see them here. Or, your aspx is not referencing this as your codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your .aspx page and hit `Convert to Web Application` - that will create and populate the designer file.